# MySQL get only results which are not in other table

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to get results which are not in other table my query so far is

> `SELECT
>       student.StudentID
>   FROM
>       student
>   INNER JOIN studentgroup ON studentgroup.StudentID Not Like student.StudentID
>   WHERE
>       student.StudentID NOT LIKE studentgroup.StudentGroupID
>   GROUP BY
>       student.StudentID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using left join and not null, this will return all the students who are not present in the studentgroup table.

```
select
s.StudentID from student s
left join studentgroup sg on sg.StudentID = s.StudentID
where sg.StudentID is null
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you help me with one other thing I am trying to use this Query 'SELECT
 CONCAT(Name,' (',StudentID, ')' ) as StudentID, StudentID
FROM
 student
LEFT JOIN studentgroup ON studentgroup.StudentID = student.StudentID
WHERE
 studentgroup.StudentID IS NULL' but i am getting [Err] 1052 - Column 'StudentID' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Yes you need to use alias `SELECT CONCAT(s.Name,' (',s.StudentID, ')' ) as StudentID  FROM student s LEFT JOIN studentgroup sg ON sg.StudentID = s.StudentID WHERE sg.StudentID IS NULL`